# How to set list source when asynchronous void is finished?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have following code. It works, however I need to invoke `ListFiles()` manually otherwise `ListView` show no items. `GetItems()` must be run asynchronously and this is the problem. How to change this code to work correctly?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupsCVS"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

private ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList;

//get files in directory and list them
public async void GetItems()
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await selectedFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        Manager.ItemsList.Add(file);
    }
}

//read list items and display in listview
public void GetFiles()
{
    GroupsCVS.Source = Manager.ItemsList;
}
```

Comment: why not make `GetItems()` return a `Task`? does it needs to void

Comment: Not sure what your exact problem is. You could easily call GetFiles first, then await GetItems (if it would return a Task).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clemens has given correct answer that call `GetFiles` first then await `GetItems`. It means that before invoked `GetFiles` method and the `Manager.ItemsList` has been modified.

And you could also listen  ObservableCollection [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event. This will ensure that `GroupsCVS.Source` can be set the latest value. The problem is GetFiles will be called many times. The better way is that you could refactor the code via Clemens's approach.

```
ItemsList.CollectionChanged += ItemsList_CollectionChanged;

private void ItemsList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GetFiles();
}
```